# Attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: django, django-models

This is the structure of my app:

```
media
packsapp
-migrations
-templates
-templatetags
-views1
-__init__.py
-apps.py
-barcode.py
-decorators.py
-forms.py
-models.py
-urls.py
-views.py
pfep
-migrations
-templates
-__init__.py
-admin.py
-apps.py
-forms.py
-models.py
-pfep_views.py
-tests.py
-urls.py
```

I have two apps named `packsapp` and `pfep` but when I tried to import `decorators` from the packsapp to the pfep like this:

pfep_views.py

```
from ..packsapp.decorators import employee_required
```

It is giving me the following error:

> ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

The main URLS.py is like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('packsapp.urls')),
    path('pfep/', include('pfep.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

Why am I getting the above error ? Is there something wrong with the import ?

Answer (score 0):

Both of your apps are at the root of your project. You need to create a wrapping package or add an `__init__.py` file to your project root. I'd recommend the first.

```
media
project_name
-__init__.py
-packsapp
--migrations
-- ...
-pfep
--migrations
-- ...
```